# Is it necessary to call super in viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I am trying to understand the scenario of the method calls to view did/will appear and disappear.

What I did is selecting the table cell (higlights in grey) , go to detail view and go back and deselect the selected row (remove the selected cell grey color).

Here are my methods:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    DLog(@"%@ did appear", self);
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (_isPushed) {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
        _isPushed=NO;
    }
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    DLog(@"%@ will appear", self);
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  //If I remove this super call , then it works fine and there is no delay in deselecting the table cell
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    DLog(@"%@ will disappear", self);
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    _isPushed=YES;
}
```

So , when I put breakpoint the flow goes like this:

**without super call:**

*while pushing to new VC:*

```
current viewWillDisappear    //makes sense
new viewWillAppear           //makes sense
current viewDidAppear         // doesnt make sense , y this should get called as the view is already appeared?
current viewWillDisappear     // make sense
current viewDidDisappear      //make sense
new viewDidAppear           //make sense
```

*while coming back from pushed VC:*

```
current viewWillDisappear
new viewDidDisappear
current viewDidDisappear
new viewDidAppear
```

**with super call:**

*while pushing to new VC:*

```
current viewWillDisappear
new viewWillAppear
current viewDidAppear
current viewWillDisappear
current viewDidDisappear
new viewDidAppear
```

*while going back from pushed VC:*

```
current viewWillDisappear
new viewDidDisappear
current viewDidDisappear
new viewDidAppear
```

The flow is pretty much the same either I use super call or not.
But the problem I am facing is, when I use super call in viewWillAppear, there is a delay(around >1second) in deselcting the cell.

If I dont use the super call in viewWillAppear , there is no delay and the cell is deselcting (around <0.5 seconds)

I am not sure to use super call or not.

Can anyone please tell me why there is a delay in deselecting the cell?

Comment: If you are not adding any code do not bother with adding the method. Apple templates add potentially useful ["Boilerplate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) methods, if you do not need them, that is do not need to add code to them, delete them. In this example you can just delete the methods: `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:) states you must:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method is called before the receiver's view is about
>   to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are
>   configured for showing the view. You can override this method to
>   perform custom tasks associated with displaying the view. For example,
>   you might use this method to change the orientation or style of the
>   status bar to coordinate with the orientation or style of the view
>   being presented. **If you override this method, you must call `super` at
>   some point in your implementation**.

Comment: I am confused in the name overrride. As you can see, the viewWillAppear doesnt include any code, so what is the point to override that method?

Comment: I called super in viewDidAppear because, I wrote some code in it, and it needs to be overriden!!!

Comment: It means when you override the base class implementation, as you have done.

Comment: the delay in deselcting the cell definetley means the viewDidappear is getting called with a delay ? Or where does the issue lies in?

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, call `super`. I've seen weird things happen in nav controllers when I forget.

In this case, if you have a UITableViewController, try using its `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` flag to clear the selection for you.

Comment: I work in an organisation and they dont use tableviewcontrollers. Everywhere it is just tableview!!!!

Comment: Try putting the deselect in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear.

Comment: in that case, the selection gets deselcted right away.

Comment: Sure... though it'd be easy to wrap in a `performSelector: withDelay:0.2`, right? That you could fine tune to make the selection disappear exactly when you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's necessary to write super.